# More simplified / efficient way to define variables when there are errors

Tags: python, excel

I am just learning python and can't come up with a more efficient way to write a set of code. The code looks through the result of an API call and pulls out specific text into a cell (which eventually goes into Excel). When it can't find the specific text, it returns "NA" for that specific cell. The way I currently have it written is:

```
try:
    company = 'company name in API output' #path to the value of the key that matches company name
except: 
    company:'NA' #Sometimes, the company name isn't in the API output and this results in an IndexError, so it should return 'NA' in the specific cell
try:
    location = 'location of company in API output' #path to the value of the key that matches location
except:
    location = 'NA'
# etc... This data eventually gets appended to a table row by row and then exported to pandas if that is helpful to know.
```

The code runs fine as is so I don't need help with that aspect. What I'd like input on is whether there is a better way to write the code, perhaps using a function or other python code so that I don't have to have try/excepts for every variable BUT written in a way so that even if one variable results in an error, not all variables become 'NA.' Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Your exception catch everthing. Better use normal if condition to check if API is correct or whatever.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop? One to go over the companies, one for the locations, etc? Inside the loop you could have `try/except` block as you do now. There wouldn't be a need to copy it for every variable, just once inside the loop.

Comment: what data structure is used for API output? If it is dict you can use something like this API_response.get('location', 'NA')

Comment: Concerning @Marcin 's comment: have a look here https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions